# setInterval append link only once without clearing Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, setinterval

I am looking to append a link to a div when another div has some specific words in it but I am looking to append the link only once instead of multiple times like I am getting in my result so far I want to keep the `setInterval` running though instead of clearing it.

```
setInterval(function() {

            if ($('._3hHP2tdBjL:contains("Nice to meet you!")').length >= 0) {                   $(".link-2").remove();
                $("#sendImg-3").append('<a class="link-1" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link 1</a>');
            } else if {
                if ($('._3hHP2tdBjL:contains("Nice to meet you Two!")').length >= 0) {
                    $(".link-1").remove();
                    $("#sendImg-4").append('<a class="link-2" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link 2</a>');
                }
            }, 500);
```

I assume `.empty()` or `.detach()` is what I am looking for or both from what I have read I am just struggling to get it to work with `.length`

Comment: jsFiddle example?

Comment: *Why* do you not want to clear the interval?

Comment: `setInterval` + only once  = `setTimeOut`.